# r - create .gz file from .txt file in R

Tags: r, gzip

Trying to find a way to use R as a converter to produce .gz archives from .txt documents.

Tried using `gzip` but seems this function is no longer supported by the `utils` package.

Tried using `tar` but this can be used to produce .gzip files and not .gz files.

I know how to automate this process for many files but so far cannot find a function that can be used to produce a .gz file.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What code did you try exactly? Are you saying there is a different between "gzip" and "gz" files? Aren't the file extensions pretty arbitrary? Have you looked at `gzfile()`? What OS are you on?

Comment: I need .gz files and not .gzip files. Will provide a code sample in the question